# DateTime Variable -- Kmeans

Tags: clustering, k-means, feature-engineering

Suppose I have a DateTime variable that I want to cluster on. I only really care about the **day**, **hour**, and **minute**. Is it wrong to create a column in my data set for each of these or should I keep the one DateTime variable and convert it to *double* with the following formula:

```
continousDateTime = day + hour/24 + minute/1440
```

If I do it this way, I feel like I will be losing out on the minute granularity that I need to conserve. Let me know your thoughts and experiences :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your conversion formula does not make sense. You should convert time to minutes after some specific time point (using, e.g., your first timestamp or 1970-01-01 00:00:00 as an "anchor time"). The formula will look something like this:

```
delta_minutes = day*24*60 + hour*60 + minute
```

Much software will do this automatically. For instance, in R, `POSIXct` internally stores timestamps as seconds since the beginning of 1970 UTC.

Once you have converted your timestamps like this, you can cluster away.

If you keep your day, hour and minute in three separate columns, you will cluster in three dimensions. Then timestamps seven hours apart on one day (e.g., 2016-06-30 10:00 and 2016-06.30 17:00) may be sorted into *different* clusters, whereas timestamps with the same hour and minute three days apart (e.g., 2016-06-30 10:00 and 2016-07-02 10:00) may be sorted in the *same* cluster. This is presumably not what you want.

Comment: Ah, I see thank you for your input. :) I don't understand why my formula is incorrect though... Your formula has units of minutes and mine has units of days.

Comment: Ah, you are right. Sorry. I misunderstood. My preconceptions got in the way.